# Recursive join with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have data in the following format:

```
FromStateID ToStateID Seconds
1           2         10
2           3         20
3           4         15
4           5         5
```

I need the following output

```
FromStateID ToStateID Seconds
1           2         10
2           3         20
3           4         15
4           5         5
1           3         10+20
1           4         10+20+15
1           5         10+20+15+5
2           4         20+15
2           5         20+15+5
3           5         15+5
```

This output shows the total time taken `FromStateId` to `ToStateId` in every combination in chronological order.

Please help.

Comment: Is the max stateid 5? Or could there be more? We need to know the maximum number. And do you really want a string such as "10+20+15+5" returned? Or do you want the result e.g. 50?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a statement of input and output is not a question.

Comment: Max state id could be more than 5 and i need the sum of seconds not string. I added it to better explain it

Comment: I had worked on it and tried to solve this problem using self join but realized that's not the way to go. I knew recursive query would work here but i have never used it. Also i already put in 1.5 days to come up with a solution and couldn't spare any more time as my task is in the red.

Comment: Is there any possibility of a cycle, e.g. if going from state `4` to state `1` was possible then you would need to handle `1` → `2` → `3` → `4` → `1` → ...?

Comment: There is a possibility but we have handled it differently. If its going from 3 -> 2 or 3 -> 1 the time (in seconds) is considered against step 3 -> 4 because i don't think any other way would make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a recursive CTE that follows the links:

```
with cte as (
      select FromStateID, ToStateID, Seconds
      from t
      union all
      select cte.FromStateId, t.ToStateId, cte.Seconds + t.Seconds
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.toStateId = t.FromStateId
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cb243d7fd6dfc10cdc5d097e976bcea) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon LinOff is the better solution. Below is another option to achieve the same.

You can achieve this using CROSS JOIN and GROUP BY

```sql
DECLARE @table table(FromStateId int, ToStateId int, seconds int)

insert into @table 
values
(1           ,2         ,10),
(2           ,3         ,20),
(3           ,4         ,15),
(4           ,5         ,5 );

;with cte_fromToCombination as
(select f.fromStateId, t.tostateId
from
(select distinct fromStateId from @table) as f
cross join
(select distinct toStateId from @table) as t
)
select c.FromStateId, c.ToStateId, t.sumseconds as Total_seconds 
from cte_fromToCombination as c
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT sum(t.seconds)
from
@table as t
WHERE t.ToStateId <= c.ToStateId
) as t(sumseconds)
where c.tostateId > c.fromStateId
order by FromStateId,ToStateId
```

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| FromStateId | ToStateId | Total_seconds |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
|           1 |         2 |            10 |
|           1 |         3 |            30 |
|           1 |         4 |            45 |
|           1 |         5 |            50 |
|           2 |         3 |            30 |
|           2 |         4 |            45 |
|           2 |         5 |            50 |
|           3 |         4 |            45 |
|           3 |         5 |            50 |
|           4 |         5 |            50 |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Venkat. But out of 10 your query gives 3 correct and 7 wrong values. i didn't thought this can be achieved using joins but your query is close to output correct values.

Comment: @AmarSale, I had a small bug in the code. Fixed the same. It is working properly now. thanks for pointing the same to me :-)